# how to read data in file and store in 2-dim array c++

Tags: arrays, ifstream

I have data.txt file.

```
data.txt
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6
9999 hello hello hello
```

How can I reade the file then store the first line into an array[2][2], and store the second line into an array[3][3], and stop reading no matter what is left in the file?

Comment: Your question says C, but you have tagged it with fstream. I  assume you meant C++?

Comment: sry...typo it should be in c++

Comment: Please post the code that you've written so far, what you think it's doing, and what you want changed.

Answer (score 0):

the most simple way is use getline to read the whole line, first, and then use stringstream or sscanf().

ie

ifstream infile(filename);

infile.getline(buffer,1024,'\n');

sscanf(buffer,"%d %d %d %d',&arr[0],&arr[1],&arr[2],&arr[3]);